# Common Lisp equivalent of virtualenv or rvm?

Tags: common-lisp

Is there something similar to the Python utility [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) or Ruby utility [rvm](https://rvm.io/)?

I want to switch SBCL to Clozure CL, for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Management of software systems would be done by something like ASDF (define software systems and actions for them) and [Quicklisp](http://www.quicklisp.org) (downloading of software systems via central registration). AFAIK it does not deal with multiple versions of a software systems, such that you can say which version to load. Using different Lisps with the same library should work, since each Lisp usually has a different file type for compiled code (and/or uses a different directory for the compiled code).

Answer (score 0):

It's not "fully" in the sense of rvm. But the slime software has support for nearly any Common Lisp. You start in emacs with M-x lisp-you-want.

I'm not fully sure if Clozure CL is supported. Anyway the homepage of SLIME is at:
http://common-lisp.net/project/slime/

What it does not support is the installation of diverse Common Lisps. You either install them manualla or via your package management software (e.g apt in Debian)